# Slow execution of a loop in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically what I am looking for is any recommendations you can provide me to make this piece of code to execute faster.

The intention of this piece of code its basically by testing some conditions obtain a score and the questions related for each profile selected, and print those scores in the "Results Sheet" and print the questions in Sheets assigned with the name of the profile.

Through some quick and basic testing I discovered whenever the loop starts to print either the results or the questions its where the slow execute starts.

Sorry for the mess on the code I just started programming in Apps 
Script several weeks ago.

**EDIT**

*To be quite more specific Im trying to find out if there is any work around to print the questions in the different sheets and values of the profiles. I took a look at the similar question and he addresses a loop using for..in, Im still trying to find out if there is any other logical process I can do to get those values.*

```js
var iGrade1 = 0;
 var iGrade2 = 0.5;
 var iGrade3 = 1;
 var resultsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Results');

 var iStartingColumn = 5;
 var iCellD = 'D';
 var iCellE = 'E';
 var iTotCounter = 2;
 var amountProfiles = profileSheet.getRange
 (2, perfilSheet.getLastColumn()).getValue();

 var iTotPerf = 0;
 var iPT = 1;
 var aResizeP = 1;

  for( i = 2; i< questionsSheet.getLastRow()  ; i++ ){
    //Range 
    sBI = 'B' + i;
    sDI = 'D' + i;

   //Copies values like 1|2|3|4|, 3|4|,  2|3|, etc.
   profileCodes = questionsSheet.getRange(sDI).getValue();


    for(j = 0; j < amountProfiles; j++){
//There is a checkbox where user selects if he wants      that profile or not
    if(profileSheet.getRange(1,iStartingColumn).getValue()
    === 'Yes'){
    var sheetProfile =             SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName
(profileSheet.getRange(3, iStartingColumn).getValue());

    var totProfile = profileSheet.getRange(perfilSheet.getLastRow(), iStartingColumn).getValue();
    //User can select in a checkbox between 'Bad' 'Regular' and 'Good'
     if( ( questionsSheet.getRange( sBI ).getValue() === '× Bad' )  ){     
       if(profileCodes.split("|").indexOf( String( perfilSheet.getRange(2, iStartingColumn).getValue() ) ) > -1 ){
         iTotPerf = iTotPerf + iGrade1; }
    }

     else if( ( questionsSheet.getRange( sBI ).getValue() === ' ± Regular' )  ){
      if(  profileCodes.split("|").indexOf( String( perfilSheet.getRange(2, iStartingColumn).getValue() ) ) > -1 ){
         iTotPerf = iTotPerf + iGrade2; }
    }

    else if( ( questionsSheet.getRange( sBI ).getValue() === '✓ Good' )  ){
       if(profileCodes.split("|").indexOf( String( perfilSheet.getRange(2, iStartingColumn).getValue() ) ) > -1 ){
         iTotPerf = iTotPerf + iGrade3; }
    }

    if ( profileCodes.split('|').indexOf(String
    (perfilSheet.getRange(2, iStartingColumn).getValue()))
    > -1){
    questionsSheet.getRange('A' + i + ':' + 'C' + i)
    .copyTo(sheetProfile.getRange('A' + iPT),SpreadsheetApp
    .CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,false);
    sheetProfile.autoResizeColumn(aResizeP);
    }

    if(iTotPerf != 0){
    resultadosSheet.getRange(iCellD + iTotCounter).setValue(resultadosSheet.getRange(iCellD + iTotCounter).getValue() + iTotPerf);
    resultsSheet.getRange(iCellE + iTotCounter).setValue( ( (resultsSheet.getRange(iCellD + iTotCounter).getValue() * 100)/ totPerfil )/ 100);
    }
    }

    iTotPerf = 0;
    iTotCounter++;
    iStartingColumn++;   
    }


    iPT += 1; 
    iTotCounter = 2;
    iStartingColumn = 5; 
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very slow execution of for...in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938168/very-slow-execution-of-for-in-loop)

Comment: @YairHernandez Welcome. I sympathise but there is hope! Your script is slow due to the `getValue` calls **inside** the loop; `copyTo` and `setValue` commands can be expensive too. Please share your spreadsheet, or a sanitised version of it, so we can understand the sheet structure and also consider options. You can also diagnose a fair bit yourself by using the Execution Transcript (Script Editor > View) - it shows the amount of time that is being occupied by each process. I sometimes copy/paste mine to a spreadsheet where I can calculate the results in detail. Post a comment when you respond.